# Google Map Iterate through all the objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am dynamically loading json map data. Once the data is loaded, I wanted to iterate over all items (Features) on the map. Then I want to add a 'listener' when a user clicks on the feature.

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
   console.log(feature);   

   map.data.addListener(feature, 'click', function(event) {
        console.log('click'); 
   }); 

});
```

When I console.log(feature) there are objects. (see image)

Other examples show map.data.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(event) {////}

Loggin shows 'feature.getGeometry().getType().toLowerCase()' = polygon so I know I have good objects.

How do I iterate through all the objects and listen for the click?
[image]

Comment: You should just be able to add a click listener to the data layer like [this google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event), replacing the "mouseover" with "click"  (outside of the .`forEach`).  What are you trying to do in the "click" event?

Comment: @geocodezip -- Wow .. it worked !  Can you please post a completed Answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click listener to the data layer like [this google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event), replacing the "mouseover" with "click" (outside of the .forEach).

```
// Set click event for each feature.
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click'); 
});
```