# How to loop through Google Maps features loaded with loadGeoJson

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've successfully loaded and displayed some polygons in a Google Maps API v3 using this:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('../somename.geojson');
```

Now I want to add a click listener to each of the polygons in the map, but all guides to do this already assume that I know which array contains my polygons, which I don't.

I'm having no luck looking through the object map created with:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});
```

The array of polygons must be somewhere inside this object, right? Anyone know where?

Comment: related question: [Google Map Iterate through all the objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905924/google-map-iterate-through-all-the-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for the Data class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data) describes the `forEach` method:

> **forEach(callback:function(Data.Feature))** | Return Value:  None
>   Repeatedly invokes the given function, passing a feature in the collection to the function on each invocation. The order of iteration through the features is undefined.